Soundproofing evelated-floor apartment
I live in a coop and have neighbor that uses a machine at night. I can feel the vibration of the machine even while I'm laying in my bed. Would soundproofing helps even if my floor was built elevated and is a hardwood material?

Perhaps post a photo. And describe the construction

This is a difficult problem.  You say you feel the machine, which is different from hearing the machine.  Is there no auditory component here?

Have you reviewed the other questions tagged soundproofing? Doing anything significant to an apartment is difficult, unless you have access to the source of the noise.

To stop feeling the machine in bed, it may be simpler to build an elevated cushioned platform for the bed to sit on, instead of the whole floor.
Note: try sitting on a piece of plywood resting on a filled car or truck tire inner tube while the neighbor's machine is running. If you cannot feel the vibrations while on the inner tube, then putting the bed on an inner-tube-supported bed platform, instead of the legs or structure it has now, may help.
The inner tubes can provide a springy suspension for the platform and bed, hopefully isolating the neighbor's machine's vibrations in the floor.
I'd make the plywood platform the same size as the bed mattress. This platform will be the new legs of the bed.
Then put appropriate-size tire inner tubes under the platform. Pump up the inner tubes, and the platform will elevate off the floor on the pressurized air. A "grid" of some 6 or 8 tubes may provide enough support.
Lay in bed while the machine is running. You may have to experiment with different pressure levels to find the sweet spot where the vibrations are reduced or eliminated. (I think highly-pressurized tubes may become more rigid and allow vibration through.)
Of course, the bed will tilt heavily while getting into it because of the floating support provided by the tubes (rather like how getting into a small boat rocks the boat). You can add a slightly-elevated wood skirt around the plywood platform that can serve as hard support to prevent the bed platform from tipping while entering or exiting the bed.
Once you have the correct air pressure set in the tubes, lay centered in bed and have someone measure how far from the floor the platform is. Add a skirt 1 cm (half inch) less than the measured height. When you get into bed, it will rock only the 1cm distance to bring the skirt to the floor. Then when you lay centered in the bed, the platform will flatten out again and the whole skirt will be off the floor, and the bed will rest on the inner tubes.

If just vibration, would not just hard foam(insulation) pads/sheets with plywood(to hold the bed legs) on top work?

It's possible, that's another concept to try. But I'd lead with squishy support rather than hard to try to filter out vibration. Same as how larger capacitors filter AC ripple in a DC supply better than smaller capacitors.
